# Calling keys in C++ for their values

Tags: c++

Hi I need to type a code which calls the key and its values such as "Tokyo 10 23 32". I can't use arrays or vectors how can I store my data? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. `std::map` uses a Red-Black tree, and `std::unordered_map` uses a Hash Table.

Comment: Any other alternatives in case it is restricted too?

Comment: maps are the canonical way to store items as key/value pairs. Based on the wording of your question (using the words "key" and "value") it sounds like `map` or `unordered_map` is the *expected* solution. Ask your professor.

Comment: Since the OP "can't use arrays or vectors", then `std::(unordered_)map` is *likely* out of the question too, unless this is for an assignment that is *specifically* related to them. Another option would be to use a manual list. `std::map` is usually implemented as a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), `std::unordered_map` as a hash table, both of which can be implemented by hand.